# Command raised an exception: TypeError: index 'wallet' cannot be applied to Cursor instances. Discord.py?

Tags: python, mongodb, discord, discord.py

I am making a search command for my discord bot with mongodb. This command was not showed anywhere so im testing it around.This is what i made so far but i get the error shown in the title. I dont know how to fix it so if you know please tell me. It would really help it all. Here is my code

```
  async def search(self, ctx):
        apple = [
            'Shoe',
            'Sink',
            'Car'
        ]
        await ctx.send(f'What would you like to search? \n``{apple}``')
        await open_account(self, ctx.author)
        
        document = collection.find({"userid":ctx.author.id})
        wallet_amt = document['wallet'] 
        
        def check(msg):
            return msg.author== ctx.message.author and message.channel==ctx.message.channel and str(msg.content) in ['Shoe','Sink','Car']
        
        msg = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
        if str(msg.content) == 'Sink':
            earnings = random.randint(50,200)
            await ctx.send(f'You chose to search the ``Sink`` You found <:Coin:842441305242206228> **{earnings}**! Why did you even look there?')
            collection.update_one({"userid":ctx.author.id}, {"inc":{"wallet":earnings}})
        else:
            await ctx.send('XD')
```

```
Ignoring exception in command search:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/container/cogs/economy.py", line 51, in search
    wallet_amt = document['wallet']
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 650, in __getitem__
    raise TypeError("index %r cannot be applied to Cursor "
TypeError: index 'wallet' cannot be applied to Cursor instances

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: index 'wallet' cannot be applied to Cursor instances
```

Comment: Please post the *whole* traceback, not only a random line.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I edited it with the full traceback

Comment: what does 'document' look like if you print it?

Comment: @Guddi It looks like ```{'_id': ObjectId('60b6577d4a2ad601d7d1ae81'), 'userid': 751405982562648146, 'wallet': 0, 'bank': 52557}
```

Answer (score 1):

`find()` returns a cursor; you likely want `find_one()` which returns a dictionary.

```
document = collection.find_one({"userid":ctx.author.id})
```